# custom UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want create custom UIActivityViewController. I create it and it works good. I have some elements in it and its ok. Now I place they in one line. How can I create UIActivityViewController with  2 lines of elements.

Now my code is:

```
 - (id)init

 if (self = [super init])
 {
    FacebookActivity *facebookActivity = [[FacebookActivity alloc]init];
    TwitterActivity *twitterActivity = [[TwitterActivity alloc]init];
    EmailActivity *emailActivity = [[EmailActivity alloc]init];
    OpenInSafariActivity *openInSafari = [[OpenInSafariActivity alloc]init];
    OpenInWebActivity *openInWeb = [[OpenInWebActivity alloc]init];
    CopyLink *copyLink = [[CopyLink alloc]init];

    copyLink.delegate = self;
    facebookActivity.delegate = self;
    twitterActivity.delegate = self;
    emailActivity.delegate = self;
    openInWeb.delegate = self;
    openInSafari.delegate = self;

    self = [self initWithActivityItems:@[emailActivity] applicationActivities:@[openInWeb, openInSafari, facebookActivity, twitterActivity, emailActivity, copyLink]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
    {
    };
 }
 return self;
```

And the second question is how can I set color of bottom view with all UIActivityViewController’s elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the implementation of your custom `UIActivity` classes you need to implement the following class method:

```
+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory {
    return UIActivityCategoryAction; // or return UIActivityCategoryShare
}
```

The return value defines which row the activity will appear on in the activity view. `UIActivityCategoryShare` puts the activity on the 1st row and `UIActivityCategoryAction` puts it on the 2nd row.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the sample Code :https://github.com/ArpitLokwani/ALCustomActivityView

Comment: link broken, plz fix